# Does `instanceof` produce a static type qualifier?

Tags: java, typescript, programming-languages, static-typing

In Typescript one can take a symbol and use its signature (and everything compiler knows about the object) as a valid type qualifier. This allows you to do this:

```js
const foo: number = 3

const bar: typeof foo = 4
```

Is it possible in any other languages? I was told that it is possible in Java using the `instanceof` but I struggled to find any documentation on this keyword aside from dynamic type-checking.

Comment: yes, it is dynamic in java; it looks like you are looking for a `cast` instead in java

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all:

> Does `instanceof` produce a static type qualifier?

Not at all. It is just an operator that returns a boolean result. It tells you `if A is an instance of B`. Not more, not less.

In Java, all type information (at least at runtime) boils down to the things that java.lang.Class gives you.

In other words: when you `int foo = 3` in Java, the best thing you hope for would be `Class<?> bar = int.class`. Also note that there is no generic way to get to the Class object of "something".

The only slightly "advanced experience" was added with the new `var` keyword. Which basically allows you to now write down types explicitly, but let the compiler handle them completely.

The one additional semantical element that `var` gives you: the ability to "name" something that otherwise has no name:

```
var obj = new Object() {
  private void test() {
    System.out.println("anonymous test");
  }
};
obj.test(); // works!
```

( from the java specialist newsletter, issue [263](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue263.html) )